# Has anyone statistics for the number of users completing a registration for a service?

Tags: forms, registration

I have a client and their website has a registration form the user needs to complete before they can use a service. The registration has 3 steps.

The percent of users completing this process *once they complete the first step* is 26%.

My question: has anyone any data for typical completion rates for registration once the process has been started?

So % of users starting the process, not % users of all that website's traffic

Comment: The percentages wildly differ, depending on a mountain of factors.

Answer (score 1):

Your website may not be ecommerce - but [this report](http://baymard.com/lists/cart-abandonment-rate) reports a blended average of 68.63% abandonment rate.